Will these scripted updates leave my ElasticSearch document in the expected state?
Suppose I have the following document in ElasticSearch:
{
  "version": 1,
  "meal": "breakfast"
}

Suppose I run the following code to attempt 2 simultaneous conditional updates to the document, and no error is thrown:
    async function runScript(source) {
        await client.update({
            index: 'testindex',
            id: 12345,
            body: {
                script: {
                    lang: "painless",
                    source: source
                }
            }
        });
        return;
    }

    const promise2 = runScript('if (ctx._source.version < 3) {ctx._source.meal = "dinner"; ctx._source.version = 3}');
    const promise1 = runScript('if (ctx._source.version < 2) {ctx._source.meal = "lunch"; ctx._source.version = 2}');
    await promise1;
    await promise2;

If I check the document again an hour later, and nobody else changed it since, is it guaranteed that no matter what order the requests executed in, the document will contain:
{
  "version": 3,
  "meal": "dinner"
}

?
i.e. is it guaranteed that the right update wins?
